# error after input table in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

i have got error after i input table.
i want to display some of data that has my name on it from my database to jtable.
so i drag and drop jtable,
i edit the elements of jtable,
and then i go to my query and change it.

after that
netbeans give me this error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdesktop/beansbinding/Property
at main.Login.jButton1ActionPerformed(Login.java:142)
at main.Login.access$000(Login.java:20)
at main.Login$1.actionPerformed(Login.java:61)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at
```

but for the gui i let netbeans to build it can you help me..?? i don't how to make jtable using netbeans

[my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl0fd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all NoClassDefFoundError mean that some libraries you imported has being missing at the run time. thats why you didn't received any syntax error at the compile time. P.S : **ClassNotFoundError** vs **NoClassDefFounderror** has a total different stories.
So I have few suggestion

1. 1.In your command line parameters Unix (and OSX) have different classpath separator than windows (: instead of ;)
2. Check your important jars classes.I think you may be using a wroung version on one of important jars(Assusming you are not using
   Maven)

**UPDATE:**

- Support for JSR 296 has being removed from Netbeans newer
  versions(since 7.1), basically the framework that was behind your
  "Java Desktop Application" project template) has been abruptly
  dropped.
- So what you have to do is it is not necessary to use the SAF in order
  to visually design a form. NetBeans swing-designer (known as Matisse)
  can be used to design any JFrame, JDialog, JPanel, etc.

You just have to

Right click -> New -> JFrame Form...

and you're ready to drag-and-drop!

Comment: could it be that because i'm using connector libraries..??

Comment: can be.Because I faced on the same problem in many times. The main reson you can't catch it directly because the jar's you important may require another dependent jars. those dependent jar you have included is not well fitted

Comment: but i 'm using this libraries before and it works. although i use it in eclipse for my assignment

Comment: what is the Version of netbeans are you using

Comment: netbeans IDE 8.1, i want to ask that if i want to connect to my database i just need to import data form select database in my case mysql connector and then just input my database and click finish right..?? i don't need  to add some property in connection properties..??

Comment: thats different kind of scenario :) . But you should know that there is bug in netbeans from version since from 7.0.1  and also can you put a screenhot of showing how you include the database to netbeans project. Thank you

Comment: refere this link for the bugs discreption https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=204661

Comment: it seems to me you added the jdbc driver.How did you added username and password for the mysql databse inside your Java program.

Comment: i have connection manager and user bean class that allow me to insert username and password, hmm could it be cause my query in my jtable my query SELECT * FROM User WHERE type = admin

Comment: No .I dont think as your error report it wasnt becasue of the Mysql or any DB related scenario please refer to my updated answer